# Why would one component's ActionListener affect another one?

Tags: java, swing

In my program, I have several swing components, a problem I came across was that my ActionPerformed method would fire twice if an action event was triggered. I eventually figured out that this was due to my ***confirmBtn***(JButton) having an ActionListener added to it twice by accident.

However, there is one thing that I don't understand and I am fairly new to Java so forgive me for asking something that may seem obvious:

I have given all my components action listeners like this:

```
confirmBtn.addActionListener(this);
```

and then reference them in my `ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method like this:

```
if(e.getSource() == confirmBtn)
    Execute code....
```

My question is, why then, by accidentally giving just **one** component an extra ActionListener, has it affected all the other components that are called in ActionPerformed method by making them also be fired twice? is it something to do with the way I have given each component ActionListeners?

Comment: Also, I am sorry if the question title is incorrectly worded as it was difficult to try and explain

Comment: So you mean that by accidently adding the same action listener to the same component twice (causing it to be called twice), all your other action listeners added to other components were triggered twice as well?

Comment: yes my question is why does this happen, I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thank you for your response, I am a student learning Java and am only just getting to grips with the basic elements. My problem was I had an addBookingButton and it's event was being fired twice. When I removed the extra actionListener for confirmBtn (completely unrelated button) the addBookingButton event only fired once so I assumed that this was the reason. You're right, I probably shouldn't have jumped to that conclusion too quickly but its the only logical thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the same `ActionListener` for all components? the `this`in your statement

```
confirmBtn.addActionListener(this);
```

makes me think so. I don't recommend it as then you have to implement more complex logic inside the `actionPerformed()` method and the thing can get messed up quickly.

What I would do is create separate `ActionListener`s for each component so they work independently of one another. This can easily be done using [inner, local or anonymous classes](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/nested_inner_member_and_top). As an example, consider you have two buttons, one for confirmation and one for cancelation. My proposed structure would be:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    ...
    public void mySetup() {
        ...
        confirmBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 confirmed(e); // delegate to outer class for cleaner code
            }
        });

        canceledBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cancelled(e); // delegate to outer class for cleaner code
            }
        });
        ...
    }
    ...   
    private void confirmed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Your real confirmBtn action code 
    }

    private void cancelled(ActionEvent e) {
        // Your real cancelBtn action code
    }
    ...
}
```

This way would be more verbose, but as every component has its own `ActionListener` the possibility of unintended interactions is much smaller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so instead of having one big ActionPerformed() method with lots of if else statements for individual components, you would give each component event its own method. Am I right in saying that the way I was going about it was poor coding practice and a bad habit to get into? thanks :)

Comment: @Jake Personally I would certainly prefer several independent small methods rather than one big method that everybody calls